# How to avoid "System.ArgumentException: Not a valid expression" when using a colum name with square brackets in Spotfire SDK?

Tags: ironpython, tibco, spotfire

I've got a working IronPython script for loading an Excel file and adding its contents to an existing data source. When loading the Excel file, I'm using a *DataFlowBuilder* with an *ExpressionTransformation* to perform some data conversions, e.g. converting columns from Int to Real.

This works unless the column name contains square brackets - whenever I try to use a name containing square brackets, I get a *"System.ArgumentException: Not a valid expression: Cast([Process Time [h]] as Real)"* exception (where "*Process Time [h]*" (without the quotes) is the name of the Excel column).

**CODE**

```
transformation = ExpressionTransformation()

transformation.ColumnReplacements.Add(
         "Process Time [h]",
         "Cast([Process Time [h]] as Real)",
         ColumnSelection([DataColumnSignature("Process Time [h]", DataType.Integer)])
)
```

**Things I've tried**

- quoting the column name with double quotes `"Cast([\"Process Time [h]\"] as Real)"`
- quoting the column name with single quotes `"Cast(['Process Time [h]'] as Real)"`
- escaping the square brackets with `\` `"Cast([Process Time \[h\]] as Real)"`
- escaping the square brackets with `\\` `"Cast([Process Time \\[h\\]] as Real)"`

Any ideas? Or should I contact Tibco Spotfire support regarding this?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the square brackets by square brackets? e.g. `Cast([Process Time [[h]]] as Real)`. Not knowing Spotfire: have you tried looking at what the SDK does when it throws the exception?

Comment: Good guess (hadn't thought of using square brackets to escape square brackets) - this gets rid of the error message, but then, the column name doesn't match (the transformation isn't executed). Out of curiosity, I added a column called "Process Time [[h]]" and promptly got another (completely different) error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cast([Process Time [h]]] as Real)` should work. Note the unbalanced number of `[` and `]`.